# Filter queryset by date on prefetch_related

Tags: django, django-queryset, prefetch

I need to filter a queryset by comparing dates on related objects, but the filter its ignored.

My resumed model is:

```
class Requerimiento(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    fecha_publicacion = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
    fecha_aprobacion = models.DateField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    aprobacion = models.BooleanField()
    autor = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.nombre

class Contexto(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    requerimientos = models.ManyToManyField(Requerimiento, 
        related_name = 'contextos')

    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.nombre

class Proyecto(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    cod_proyecto = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    contextos = models.ManyToManyField('Contexto', related_name = 'proyectos')
    fecha_publicacion  = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)
    autor = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
```

And the queryset is:

```
queryset=Proyecto.objects.filter(pk=proyecto_id)\
    .prefetch_related('contextos')\
    .prefetch_related('contextos__requerimientos')\
    .filter(contextos__requerimientos__fecha_aprobacion__lte=F('fecha_publicacion'))
```

What i'm doing wrong?

*EDIT*

Looking with debug-toolbar i see the following with proyect id 2 selected in the following code

```
requerimientos = ProyectoFilter(request.GET,
    queryset=Proyecto.objects.filter(pk=proyecto_id)
    .distinct()
    .prefetch_related('contextos')
    .prefetch_related('contextos__requerimientos')
    .filter(contextos__requerimientos__fecha_aprobacion__lte=F('fecha_publicacion')))
```

First query:

```
SELECT ••• FROM "sgrs_proyecto" INNER JOIN "sgrs_proyecto_contextos" 
ON ( "sgrs_proyecto"."id" = "sgrs_proyecto_contextos"."proyecto_id" ) 
INNER JOIN "sgrs_contexto" ON ( "sgrs_proyecto_contextos"."contexto_id" =  
"sgrs_contexto"."id" ) INNER JOIN "sgrs_contexto_requerimientos" 
ON ( "sgrs_contexto"."id" = "sgrs_contexto_requerimientos"."contexto_id" ) 
INNER JOIN "sgrs_requerimiento" ON ( "sgrs_contexto_requerimientos"."requerimiento_id" = "sgrs_requerimiento"."id" ) 
WHERE ("sgrs_proyecto"."id" = 2 AND "sgrs_requerimiento"."fecha_aprobacion" 
<= "sgrs_proyecto"."fecha_publicacion")
```

Second query:

```
SELECT ••• FROM "sgrs_contexto" INNER JOIN "sgrs_proyecto_contextos" 
ON ( "sgrs_contexto"."id" = "sgrs_proyecto_contextos"."contexto_id" ) 
WHERE "sgrs_proyecto_contextos"."proyecto_id" IN (2) 
ORDER BY "sgrs_contexto"."indice_riesgo" DESC
```

Third query:

```
SELECT ••• FROM "sgrs_requerimiento" INNER JOIN "sgrs_contexto_requerimientos" 
ON ( "sgrs_requerimiento"."id" = "sgrs_contexto_requerimientos"."requerimiento_id" )
WHERE "sgrs_contexto_requerimientos"."contexto_id" IN (3, 7, 6, 4, 2, 5, 1)
```

The date filter is in the first query and should be in the third, is this correct?
How can i get the correct filter position?

Thanks

Comment: @mariodev, even when i correct the indentation this still does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, finally got it.
I took out the filter from the queryset and make this comparison in the template.

Just added the following:

```
...
{% for requerimiento in contexto.requerimientos.all %}
{% if requerimiento.fecha_aprobacion <= proyecto.fecha_publicacion %}
...
```

Hope this helps others.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the usage of prefetch_related is not correct. See first note in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related. Second, you might want to use distinct() with queries with filters on m2m relation.

The query you have posted should give you all Proyecto objects that have at least one related Requerimiento with fecha_aprobacion less or equal than its' own fecha_aprobacion. What do you expect from the query and what do you get?

Comment: I need to get from specific Proyect, all related context and all related requirements from each context. But i need to filter those requirement tah have approve_date (fecha_aprobacion) lte than the publication date (fecha_publicacion) of the Proyect. I dont mind of distinct, because in the template i'll show the result in group of context-requirements.

Comment: In debug toolbar WITHOUT the las filter i see the query like this:

    SELECT ("sgrs_proyecto_contextos"."proyecto_id") AS "_prefetch_related_val_proyecto_id", "sgrs_contexto"."id", "sgrs_contexto"."nombre", "sgrs_contexto"."descripcion", "sgrs_contexto"."critico", "sgrs_contexto"."indice_riesgo" FROM "sgrs_contexto" INNER JOIN "sgrs_proyecto_contextos" ON ( "sgrs_contexto"."id" = "sgrs_proyecto_contextos"."contexto_id" ) WHERE "sgrs_proyecto_contextos"."proyecto_id" IN (1) ORDER BY "sgrs_contexto"."indice_riesgo" DESC